# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system

Tags: java, selenium

Following previous related issues posted and given resolution, I tired everything but still getting same error for FireFox, Chrome & Internet Explorer.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


 public class Search {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\nitin\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-
  win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver.get("http://www.wikipedia.org");
    WebElement link;
    link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("English"));
    link.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement searchbox;
    searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput"));
    searchbox.sendKeys("Software");
    searchbox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be `System.setProperty()` instead of `.getProperty()`?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver, "C:\\Users\\...\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Comment: This should nail the OP's issue. Thanks

Comment: I did try with .getProperty as well, but the error remains same

Answer (score 0):

Use that gecko driver system property before driver intialization
So first line gecko property and next line driver=new so and so..

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setProperty` and declare it after providing the path to webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\nitin\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```